# Undefined reference while compiling library

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, linker

So I have this project where I use my school library, and I can't compile a program with it. It works fine on my mac, but on Linux does not work.

I did a small main file to test the problem:

```
#include "includes/libft/libft.h"

int main(void)
{
    ft_printf("hello world\n");
}
```

Here's the command that I use to compile it:

`gcc includes/libft/libft.a main.o -o test`

Here's the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `ft_printf'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And yes the library is compiled.

Comment: You may need to specify the library _after_ your `.o` file. The order matters. i.e. `gcc main.o includes/libft/libft.a -o test`

Comment: @pmacfarlane I've reopened. You can use your duplicate now.